# Partial Credit Model: How to calculate the item difficulty?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with credits of participants for several items. I would like to calculate the item difficulty of those items. With the eRm Package I can calculate the difficulty for the different categories of each item:

```
Some data:
x1 <- c(1, 2, 1, 0, 3, 3, 0, 4, 4, 1, 0, 3, 2, 0, 4, 1, NA, 1, 1, NA, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 0, 2, 1, 0)
x2 <- c(0, 1, 0, 3, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2, NA, 0, 1, 2, 2, NA, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 3)
x3 <- c(NA, NA, 3, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, NA, 3, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 3, 1, 3, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0)
x4 <- c(3, 0, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0)
x5 <- c(1, NA, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0)
dat <- data.frame(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5)

library("eRm")

Calculation of category difficulties:
PCM(dat)
PCM(dat)$etapar
```

I do not need the difficulty for the categories, but for the whole item. How can I calculate the overall difficulty of each item?

Thank you very much in advance!